# SELECT highest time without repeating

Tags: mysql

I'm not expert in MYSQL,
I have a list of videos, (ID,ANIME_ID,TIME)
I want to select top 25 rows ordered by TIME without repeating same ANIME_ID
I mean only top TIMEs of each ANIME_ID and ordered by TIME not by ANIME_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `mysql`, you can just use `group by` for this -- however, realize this will just return an arbitrary `id` if ties exist:

```
select id, anime_id, max(time) time
from videos
group by anime_id
order by max(time) desc
limit 25
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45936/2)

If you need a specific id for ties, you can establish a row number using `user-defined variables` and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
`Select distinct(anime_id) order by time limit 25`

Comment: already tried that it doesnt give me what I want, It selects 25 anime_id than order them byy time
what I want is to order eerything by time and take top 25 ones without taking the same anime_id more than once